# How to implement HTTPS connection pool with the Zend Framework / PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, https, connection-pooling

My zend application is heavily connected to another server provider of an API (XML formatted).
The exchange are done over HTTPS, therefore encrypted with SSL.

Since the zend application is doing a lot (and when I say a lot, I mean it), we are asked to use a pool of https connection, in order to avoid the renegociation of the SSL encryption for each request.

I've seen numerous implementation in J2EE or .net but nothing in PHP or Zend.

So far, we've done some tests with the keep alive or persitent parameter, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a persistence configuration flag you can set to Zend_Http_Client which should do that.  What it does is add to STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT to the stream_socket_client() call.  It should, however, be noted that this is not a *pool*, but a persistent connection.  Each Apache process will have its own connection.